# Is it possible to redirect (not forward) e-mails using Exchange 2007 to an external address?

Tags: exchange

I'd like to set up an internal e-mail address to automatically redirect all received e-mails to an external address using Exchange 2007. There are [articles](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/mf015.html) describing how to set up a forwarding rule on the server to forward e-mails, but I am assuming that this will work as a client forward, e.g. that the recipient of the e-mail will see the internal e-mail account as the sender, not the original sender of the e-mail?

Is it possible to set up a similar rule that redirects e-mails instead? I know that using Outlook you can make this distinction when using Outlook rules, but these will not redirect/forward e-mails to external addresses.

EDIT: Another option would be to only enable automatic forwarding for a single Exchange account, but from the google results I am getting neither options seems possible.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side forwarding is ***not*** the same as client-side forwarding ("Forward email" in Outlook).

Here is Microsofts own article on how to implement [mailbox forwarding on Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851509%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

As in the [example you gave](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/mf015.html), create a Contact beforehand and select that as the recipient.

Comment: How does server- and client-side forwarding differ? In particular, would the e-mail be preserved (e.g. original sender) when using server-side forwarding?